# How to include backslash in "wildcard" Replacement for find and replace?

Tags: microsoft-word

Using Microsoft Word 2013. The captures are `A` and `B`, the desired result is `A\B`, but `\1\\\2` and `\1\\2` don't work. Attempting any of these pops up a message complaining that

> The Replace With text contains a group number which is out of range

`\1\2` works, so it's not having trouble capturing the groups. Apparently I can't escape backslashes in this mockery of regex. Is it possible to accomplish this (in one step)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I can't escape backslashes

> Instead of back slash character `^92` must be used in Replace with expression

[Microsoft Word wildcards as regular expressions - Regent - Vlasov Studio (Best in class Visual Studio extensions and tools)](https://vlasovstudio.com/regent/documentation/Microsoft-Word-Wildcards-as-Regular-Expressions.html)

So use `\1^92\2` instead of `\1\\2`.